# Mount ubuntu one or similar web storage services without their clients

Tags: arch-linux, mount, automounting, webdav

I want to mount a folder to sync with my Ubuntu One account. The only restriction is that I don't want to use the client provided. I use Arch Linux if it counts. And if you can provide a general solution for all WebDAV(??) resources it would be useful and good reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mount a WebDAV resource as a drive in linux, you can use [davfs2](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2). In Debian-based distributions, this can be downloaded as the `davfs2` package from the main repositories:

```
    # apt-get install davfs2
```

I wrote a [blog entry](http://jcwomack.com/using-davfs-to-mount-a-webdav-share-as-a-drive-under-linux/) about mounting a specific WebDAV resource using davfs2 a while ago. I will outline the relevant details here.

Once you have davfs2 installed on your system, you should be able to use the `mount.davfs` (or `mount -t davfs`) command on your machine. The syntax is

```
    mount -t davfs https://webdav-server.com/path/to/remote/dav /path/to/local/mountpoint
```

Depending on how your davfs2 install is configured, you may be able to mount as a normal user, or you may need to be root (or have superuser privileges). On my Ubuntu system, I added my username to the davfs2 group (`adduser [my_username] davfs2`) and set the suid bit (using `dpkg-reconfigure`) on `mount.davfs` so that I would not need to be root to mount WebDAV resources.

If you are going to be repeatedly mounting a particular WebDAV source, you can simplify the mounting process by adding an entry to `/etc/fstab`, for example

```
    https://webdav-server.com/path/to/remote/dav /path/to/local/mountpoint davfs noauto,defaults,uid=myusername,gid=myusergroup 0 0
```

You can further simplify the mounting process by storing your username and password for the WebDAV resource in `~/.davfs2/secrets` in the following format:

```
    /path/to/local/mountpoint my_dav_username password
```

My setup had some particular quirks, the solutions to which are outlined in my [blog post](http://jcwomack.com/using-davfs-to-mount-a-webdav-share-as-a-drive-under-linux/)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I will read it more carefully the these days and come back to accept your answer or give some feedback :)

Comment: You're welcome. This is the first time I've been able to actually provide a knowledgeable answer on here, rather than just asking questions!

Comment: Hello again...thanks for your answer. It really works but unfortunately ubuntu one doesnt support webdav. Or I am doing something wrong...

Comment: I'm not sure about Ubuntu One -- never tried to use WebDAV with it before. There are other cloud services which support WebDAV which might be worth investigating. I believe [Box](http://www.box.com) has (unofficial) WebDAV support. I also think that WebDAV support can be added to Dropbox using [DropDAV](https://dropdav.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Just following up here for others that might be interested in this - see [Ubuntu's wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/TechnicalDetails) regarding the architecture.  It is **not** possible to access Ubuntu One via WebDAV.

> This provides remotely accessible disk space stored on Amazon S3.
>   Rather than using an existing protocol (eg. FTP, SFTP, NFS, Webdav)
>   access to this remote disk space is via an invented-here communication
>   protocol called "ubuntuone-storageprotocol" based on Google Protocol
>   Buffers.